# How not to write empty cells from excel while converting to xml

Tags: python, excel, xml, type-conversion

I have excel that i am trying to convert into XML.

[image]

I want to part the data into two parts that both have the start and end. So the XML should look like

```html
<Contract>
  <part>
    <Start>2023.05.08</Start>
    <End>2023.05.08</End>
    <A>1</A>
    <B>2</B>
  </part>
  <part>
    <Start>2023.05.08</Start>
    <End>2023.05.08</End>
    <C>3</C>
    <D>4</D>
  </part>
</Contract>
<Contract>
  <part>
    <Start>2023.05.08</Start>
    <End>2023.05.08</End>
    <A>2</A>
    <B>3</B>
  </part>
</Contract>
```

Columns A and B always have data and C and D sometimes do not.

The problem i have is how to skip second part when C and D do not have any data in them. I have tried with

```
for contract in tree.findall("Contract"):
part1 = ET.Element("part")
part2 = ET.Element("part")

start_date = contract.find("StartDate").text
end_date = contract.find("EndDate").text


start_date_element1 = ET.SubElement(part1, "StartDate")
start_date_element1.text = start_date
end_date_element1 = ET.SubElement(part1, "EndDate")
end_date_element1.text = end_date


start_date_element2 = ET.SubElement(part2, "StartDate")
start_date_element2.text = start_date
end_date_element2 = ET.SubElement(part2, "EndDate")
end_date_element2.text = end_date



for child in contract.findall("./"):
    contract.remove(child)
    if child.tag in [
        "A",
        "B",
    ]:
        PricePeriod1.append(child)
    elif child.tag in[
        "C",
        "D",
        
    ]:
        
        if child.text != "":
            part2.append(child)
            
        
contract.append(part1)
contract.append(part1)
```

And the XML i get is

```html
<Contract>
  <part>
    <Start>2023.05.08</Start>
    <End>2023.05.08</End>
    <A>1</A>
    <B>2</B>
  </part>
  <part>
    <Start>2023.05.08</Start>
    <End>2023.05.08</End>
    <C>3</C>
    <D>4</D>
  </part>
</Contract>
<Contract>
  <part>
    <Start>2023.05.08</Start>
    <End>2023.05.08</End>
    <A>2</A>
    <B>3</B>
  </part>
  <part>
    <Start>2023.05.08</Start>
    <End>2023.05.08</End>
    <C />
    <D />
  </part>
</Contract>
```

So is there a way how to exclude that last part when there is no data in them?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the XML with a function. Check if the tag content is none:

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def xml_branch(headings, data_row):
    # Build the XML branch for each row
    contract = ET.Element("Contract")
    part = ET.SubElement(contract, "part")
    start = ET.SubElement(part, headings[0])
    if data_row[0] is None:
        start.text = ""
    else:
        start.text = data_row[0]
    end = ET.SubElement(part, headings[1])
    if data_row[1] is None:
        end.text = ""
    else:
        end.text = data_row[1]
    a = ET.SubElement(part, headings[2])
    if data_row[2] is None:
        a.text = ""
    else:
        a.text = data_row[2]
    b = ET.SubElement(part, headings[3])
    if data_row[3] is None:
        b.text = ""
    else:
        b.text = data_row[3]
    
    part2 = ET.SubElement(contract, "part")
    start = ET.SubElement(part2, headings[0])
    if data_row[0] is None:
        start.text = ""
    else:
        start.text = data_row[0]
    end = ET.SubElement(part2, headings[1])
    if data_row[1] is None:
        end.text = ""
    else:
        end.text = data_row[1]
    c = ET.SubElement(part2, headings[4])
    if data_row[4] is None:
        c.text = ""
    else:
        c.text = data_row[4]
    d = ET.SubElement(part2, headings[5])
    if data_row[5] is None:
        d.text = ""
    else:
        d.text = data_row[5]
    return contract

def xml_branch_short(headings, data_row):
    # Build the XML branch for each row
    contract = ET.Element("Contract")
    part = ET.SubElement(contract, "part")
    start = ET.SubElement(part, headings[0])
    if data_row[0] is None:
        start.text = ""
    else:
        start.text = data_row[0]
    end = ET.SubElement(part, headings[1])
    if data_row[1] is None:
        end.text = ""
    else:
        end.text = data_row[1]
    a = ET.SubElement(part, headings[2])
    if data_row[2] is None:
        a.text = ""
    else:
        a.text = data_row[2]
    b = ET.SubElement(part, headings[3])
    if data_row[3] is None:
        b.text = ""
    else:
        b.text = data_row[3]
    return contract

# read csv file
with open('excel.csv', newline = '') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ';')   
    headings = next(reader)
    #print("Headings", headings)
    
    data = []
    for row in reader: 
       data.append(row[:])
    #print ("CSV: ",data)

# Build the complete XML
xml_root = ET.Element("Contracts")
for data_row in data:
    if data_row.count("") ==2:
        contract = xml_branch_short(headings, data_row)
        xml_root.append(contract)
    else:
        contract = xml_branch(headings, data_row)
        xml_root.append(contract)

ET.dump(xml_root)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Contracts>
  <Contract>
    <part>
      <Start>08.05.2023</Start>
      <End>08.05.2023</End>
      <A>1</A>
      <B>2</B>
    </part>
    <part>
      <Start>08.05.2023</Start>
      <End>08.05.2023</End>
      <C>3</C>
      <D>4</D>
    </part>
  </Contract>
  <Contract>
    <part>
      <Start>08.05.2024</Start>
      <End>08.05.2024</End>
      <A>2</A>
      <B>3</B>
    </part>
  </Contract>
</Contracts>
```

Comment: This still gives the empty C and D in that last part. Is it possible to make it so that those are not written?

Comment: [@JaniH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14054685/janih) I have adjusted my solution. Hope it helps now.